# How to remove kernels from previous release?

Tags: kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

I upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 system to 12.04 using a CD. After upgrading I try to remove old version kernels that appeared in grub boot menu, using the Synaptic Package Manager. But old kernel packages (example: `linux-image 3.0.0-16-generic`) do not appear in Synaptic. When I try to update GRUB, I see the kernels there. How can I remove them properly?