# How to remove kernels from previous release

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, release-management

See question [How to remove kernels from previous release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/153185/21005) which is marked as duplicate. I ask this again, because the question is special case and not handled in the answers for the related question. I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 using an installation media. Kernels from 15.10 are there at /boot, but the package management system seems to be unaware of this after upgrade. Related bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1586303). I do not know, if this happens, if you choose to upgrade in Software Updater.

Comment: You could do it very easily in a graphical interface software called MintUpdate. But it's not (yet) available for Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the kernels are not known to `dpkg`, you can remove them by hand by deleting all their files (I do this to remove locally compiled kernels: [How can I remove compiled kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594443/how-can-i-remove-compiled-kernel))

First check which kernel is running with `uname -r`

**DO NOT DELETE THE RUNNING KERNEL**

Let's say you want to delete kernel release `3.19.0-56` from your system.

You can use the release string to locate all of its files and directories. `locate -b -e 3.19.0-56` will find existing (`-e`) files & directories with the string `3.19.0-56` without listing all the files in all the directories (`-b`)

Having located them, you can append the command to remove them `rm -r` with `xargs`. Let's use the `-p` flag to make `xargs` interactive, so that we can see the targets and confirm before the command is executed. Here's the whole command:

```
locate -b -e 3.19.0-56 | xargs -p sudo rm -r
```

Then type `y` to really execute `rm -r` on the targets shown

(this throws some errors complaining that everything that is not a directory does not exist because you're attempting to delete it recursively with `-r`, but it still works and the files are really gone - check again with `sudo updatedb && locate -b -e 3.19.0-56` and nothing will be found)

Finally, to clean the boot menu, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: My system also has some /boot/abi-x.x.x-whatever files.

Comment: Linux version string in file names seems to be specific to files of the respective kernel packages and related packages. Assuming that you could find files to delete by `(version=4.2.0-35; locate "$version" | grep -o '.*'"$(printf '%s' "$version" | sed 's/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g')"'[^/]*' | sort -u)` in case of version 4.2.0-35.

Comment: Yes, but the command I gave produces a shorter list where not every file in the directories is listed. So it is enough to add those as arguments of `sudo rm -rf`.

Comment: It seems you could do the same more simply by `locate -b -e 4.2.0-35`. (Option -e guarantees it only lists existing files.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40753/discussion-between-jarno-and-zanna).

Comment: I wonder if that `updatedb` is necessary. The files are there from the beginning of installation of the distribution. Or could they be files from another co-existing OS installation?